# Can a Suppression Bonds cancel out another Suppression Bonds?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can you use a [Suppression Bonds](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Suppression%20Bonds) on a Suppression Bonds to use a creature that was Suppression Bonded and cancel it out?

Answer (score 7):

You *can* enchant one copy of Suppression Bonds with another, but it won't do anything.

The text of Suppression Bonds states "Enchant nonland permanent. Enchanted permanent can't attack or block, and its activated abilities can't be activated."

So Suppression Bonds is a nonland permanent, meaning it's a legal target for another Suppression Bonds. However, it prevents its target from three things:

1. Attacking
2. Blocking
3. Using activated abilities, which are abilities where you pay a cost to cause an effect, and are written in the form "Cost: Effect".

Since Suppression Bonds isn't a creature, it won't be attacking or blocking (unless there's another effect that changes that), so nothing will happen on that front. And its ability is not an activated ability, but a continuous effect, so it is not affected by Suppression Bonds being cast on it.